# Is it acceptable to ask to extend start date by 6 weeks?

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, start-date

I signed an offer letter from a large technology company in Jun 2017 3rd week for starting date of Aug 14, 2017.

My current employer is selling the public company to a private equity firm and so all the unvested equity would be purchased in cash. The original planned final date of closing the deal was by September and as per internal news it was expected by Aug 1st week. Now looks like it won't be done until original planned date.

I have some stocks in my current company - is it okay to ask the recruiter to extend the start date by 6 weeks so I don't lose the stock money? I regret awfully about not discussing this with the recruiter before signing, as I was expecting the deal to be complete by my joining date.

I know this is position and company specific, but want to take suggestions on what is the general consensus on this matter before I even talk to the recruiter.

Comment: If you do not ask you do not get. You are better off asking them than us.

Comment: I do not want to come out as a awful or unreliable prospective employee.. so just checking what others think of this.

Comment: Just explain the situation.

Comment: Do you own the stock, or are they just options? Why do you lose it if you leave the company?

Comment: @SethR Stock options (esp. in tech) are generally structured so that they vest over a couple of years, and if you leave in the meantime, you forfeit all unvested options.

Comment: @SethR On top of what Kaz said, many option plans vest to 100% if the company is acquired, so he has to stay long enough for the acquisition to close.

Comment: Yes it is unvested stock.

Answer (score 3):

> I have some stocks in my current company - is it okay to ask the
>   recruiter to extend the start date by 6 weeks so I don't lose the
>   stock money?

6 weeks is a long time. When I was hiring, I'd be very disappointed to learn at the last minute that the candidate needed an unexpected 6 weeks because the start date wasn't thought through fully.

That said, just ask.

While it may well make a bad first impression, it likely won't be fatal. If they wanted you badly enough, they'll likely find a way to wait. Be prepared with your reply if they say "No" - you can give up your stock options or decline the job acceptance.

If you do ask for an extension, consider not just asking for "6 weeks" unless you are willing to actually be there in 6 week - even if the sale date of your company takes longer. Instead, be honest, indicate why you are requesting the extension, indicate how long you suspect it will take, but admit that you don't really know for sure.

(For future reference, if you are anticipating a company event that you want to be around for - a bonus, an IPO, an acquisition, whatever - delay the start of your job search until after the event. This is what most people would do, specifically to avoid the kind of situation you find yourself in. These things always take longer than expected.)